# Repairing data in a Pandas dataframe when duplicate data exists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-quality

I've not had to do any heavy lifting with Pandas until now, and now I've got a bit of a situation and can use some guidance.

I've got some code that generates the following dataframe:

```
   ID_x HOST_NM   IP_ADDRESS_x SERIAL_x ID_y   IP_ADDRESS_y     COST PURCHASE_DATE ID     IP_ADDRESS SERIAL_y                   OS
0  62bf  philip  192.168.1.115    12345   32  192.168.1.115    36.78    2018-05-05  2  192.168.1.115      NaN      Debian 11 Linux
1  3a73     vic  192.168.1.145    17B0P   33  192.168.1.145   749.64    2018-07-26  3  192.168.1.145    17B0P        DSM 7.1-42661
2  4237    BILL   192.168.1.99      NaN   31   192.168.1.99  3584.83    2018-03-15  1   192.168.1.99    38174      Windows 10 LTSC
3  3027     tim   192.168.1.96    C02G7   34   192.168.1.96  1289.00    2021-10-13  4  192.168.1.100    C02G7  macOS Monterey 12.4
```

This dataframe is generated via an outer merge of three other dataframes.  The duplicate data is intended.  The idea is to fill in missing serial numbers if we have a hostname and consistent IP address on that row; I thought about getting all of the IP addresses in a row and if they are 80% consistent, use that address, else NaN.

Then at a later stage, I'll drop the redundant columns.

This is a PoC.  The above is a small example data set, but the actual data set contains around 35K unique devices (rows) and 112 columns (4 sets of redundant data).

I'm not seeing anything in Pandas that looks like it is tailor-made for this kind of situation.  Am a wrong about that?

Further examples and the code used here can be found on github [here](https://github.com/MagnetoOptical/pandas-heal-data).

The code referenced above follows below.

```
import logging
from functools import reduce

# import numpy
import pandas


log = logging.getLogger("merge")
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
ch = logging.StreamHandler()
ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
log.addHandler(ch)


r1 = [
    {
        'ID': '62bf',
        'HOST_NM': 'philip',
        'IP_ADDRESS': '192.168.1.115',
        'SERIAL': '12345',
    },
    {
        'ID': '3a73',
        'HOST_NM': 'vic',
        'IP_ADDRESS': '192.168.1.145',
        'SERIAL': '17B0P',
    },
    {
        'ID': '4237',
        'HOST_NM': 'BILL',
        'IP_ADDRESS': '192.168.1.99',
        'SERIAL': '',
    },
    {
        'ID': '3027',
        'HOST_NM': 'tim',
        'IP_ADDRESS': '192.168.1.96',
        'SERIAL': 'C02G7',
    },
]

r2 = [
    {
        'ID': '34',
        'HOST_NM': 'tim',
        'IP_ADDRESS': '192.168.1.96',
        'COST': '1289.00',
        'PURCHASE_DATE': '2021-10-13',
    },
    {
        'ID': '33',
        'HOST_NM': 'vic',
        'IP_ADDRESS': '192.168.1.145',
        'COST': '749.64',
        'PURCHASE_DATE': '2018-07-26',
    },
    {
        'ID': '31',
        'HOST_NM': 'BILL',
        'IP_ADDRESS': '192.168.1.99',
        'COST': '3584.83',
        'PURCHASE_DATE': '2018-03-15',
    },
    {
        'ID': '32',
        'HOST_NM': 'philip',
        'IP_ADDRESS': '192.168.1.115',
        'COST': '36.78',
        'PURCHASE_DATE': '2018-05-05',
    },
]

r3 = [
    {
        'ID': '2',
        'HOST_NM': 'philip',
        'IP_ADDRESS': '192.168.1.115',
        'SERIAL': '',
        'OS': 'Debian 11 Linux',
    },
    {
        'ID': '3',
        'HOST_NM': 'vic',
        'IP_ADDRESS': '192.168.1.145',
        'SERIAL': '17B0P',
        'OS': 'DSM 7.1-42661',
    },
    {
        'ID': '1',
        'HOST_NM': 'BILL',
        'IP_ADDRESS': '192.168.1.99',
        'SERIAL': '38174',
        'OS': 'Windows 10 LTSC',
    },
    {
        'ID': '4',
        'HOST_NM': 'tim',
        'IP_ADDRESS': '192.168.1.100',
        'SERIAL': 'C02G7',
        'OS': 'macOS Monterey 12.4',
    },
]


def unique(l: list) -> list:
    u = []
    for e in l:
        if e not in u:
            u.append(e)
    return list(u)


df1 = pandas.DataFrame(r1)
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(r2)
df3 = pandas.DataFrame(r3)
df_list = [df1, df2, df3]
df_keys = {
    0: ["ID", "SERIAL"],
    1: ["HOST_NM"],
    2: ["HOST_NM", "SERIAL"],
}
target_columns = ["HOST_NM", "SERIAL", "IP_ADDRESS"]
df = reduce(lambda left, right: pandas.merge(
    left, right, on=["HOST_NM"], how="outer"), df_list)
log.debug(df)

# Replace null and empty strings with numpy.NaN
# df = df.replace(r"^\s*$", numpy.NaN, regex=True)
df = df.mask(df == '')
log.debug(f'\n\n{df}')
```

Comment: Your example needs to minimal and runnable. What is the `records` package? Do we need to worry about the logging statements? If not, they're just a distraction. What, specifically, is your desired output? (as in, hard-code it into the question along with samples of the input dataframe that would generate the desire output)

Comment: Each record is a list of dictionaries.  They were removed from the main body of code and placed into records.py to keep it tidy.  My question, however, is really about finding a way to get the desired outcome preferably without iterating through df.  Apologies if that wasn’t clear.

Comment: No one can run your code without your data. Hard code samples of the dictionaries into the example, and type out what the results should be for those samples.